# How to retrieve the boolean values of the tables in php?

Tags: php, mysqli

```
<?php
include 'config.php';

$sql1="SELECT Project_id FROM assigned_project_tester  where Tester_name IN (SELECT Username FROM user_master where Username='meet.patel')";
$result=$conn->query($sql1);


while($row=$result->fetch_assoc())
{  echo $proid[]=$row['Project_id'];            //this is getting printed from table project_master table   
    echo '<br>';

} 
$i='';
for ($i=0; $i<sizeOf($proid); $i++)
{
    echo 'here are agian project names';
    echo $proid[$i];                          //this checkpoint to check array  and for loop is working or not
    echo '<br>';
   $sql2="select Test_creation,Test_execution from assigned_project_tester where Project_id =' " . $proid[$i] . "'   ";
  $result1=$conn->query($sql2);
 while($row1=$result1->fetch_assoc())      //I think it is not getting inside while loop
  { echo 'inside if ';                     //this is not getting printed .............
     echo $row1['Test_creation'];          //test_creation is boolean value and data type is tinyint in table assigned_project_tester
     echo $row1['Test_execution'];         //test_execution is boolean value and data type is tiny integer in table assigned_project_master
                                           //what i want to do is print yes if user has test_creation permission else no
  }                                        //same for test_execution I knew that value stored in database is 1 and 0 but
                                           //why it is not getting printed        
}

Here two sql file code for two tables which I am using in my code is written
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 3.3.9
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
--
-- Host: localhost
-- Generation Time: Mar 24, 2015 at 06:07 AM
-- Server version: 5.1.53
-- PHP Version: 5.3.4

SET SQL_MODE="NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;

--
-- Database: `tmtool`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `assigned_project_tester`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `assigned_project_tester` (
  `Assigned_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Project_manager` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Project_id` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Tester_name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Test_creation` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `Test_execution` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Assigned_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=61 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `assigned_project_tester`
--

INSERT INTO `assigned_project_tester` (`Assigned_id`, `Project_manager`, `Project_id`, `Tester_name`, `Test_creation`, `Test_execution`) VALUES
(45, 'Pritesh Usadadiya', 'PRJ005', 'meet.patel', 0, 0),
(46, 'Pritesh Usadadiya', 'PRJ005', 'Pritesh', 1, 1),
(47, 'Pritesh Usadadiya', 'PRJ005', 'trilok.patel', 1, 1),
(49, 'Pritesh Usadadiya', 'PRJ009', 'Pritesh', 0, 1),
(50, 'Pritesh Usadadiya', 'PRJ009', 'trilok.patel', 0, 1),
(52, 'Pritesh Usadadiya', 'PRJ011', 'trilok.patel', 1, 0),
(54, 'Pritesh Usadadiya', 'PRJ008', 'Pritesh', 1, 1),
(55, 'Pritesh Usadadiya', 'PRJ008', 'trilok.patel', 1, 1),
(56, 'Pritesh Usadadiya', 'PRJ10', 'meet.patel', 0, 1),
(57, 'Pritesh Usadadiya', 'PRJ10', 'trilok.patel', 0, 1),
(58, 'Pritesh Usadadiya', 'PRJ009', 'meet.patel', 1, 1),
(59, 'Pritesh Usadadiya', 'PRJ011', 'meet.patel', 0, 1),
(60, 'Pritesh Usadadiya', 'PRO10', 'meet.patel', 1, 1);



-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 3.3.9
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
--
-- Host: localhost
-- Generation Time: Mar 24, 2015 at 06:08 AM
-- Server version: 5.1.53
-- PHP Version: 5.3.4

SET SQL_MODE="NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;

--
-- Database: `tmtool`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
```

I want to retrieve value of Test_creation and Test_execution from table named assigned_project_tester and print yes if the value is 1 otherwise print no.I have done comments in code for you kindly check it .Well I am trying to solve this since 29 hours.All other things such as project_id are getting printed while this is only not working please help me.  Thanks in advance

Comment: try removing whitespaces in your where Clause in sql2-Query : 
"select Test_creation,Test_execution from assigned_project_tester where Project_id ='" . $proid[$i] . "'"

Comment: Yogi you've asked almost the same question yesterday, I gave you more than enough of an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm confused by some of your queries. It seems like you don't need two separate queries. Would just this one work?

```
SELECT Project_id, 
       Test_creation, 
       Test_execution 
FROM   assigned_project_tester 
WHERE  Tester_name = 'meet.patel'
```

This should get a list of all projects that "meet.patel" is assigned and their status.

Then you can just loop through the results with a while statement.

```
$result = $mysqli->query($query);

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo $row["Project_id"];
    echo $row["Test_creation"];
    echo $row["Test_execution "];
}

$result->free();
```

Comment: Actually Permission module was updated recently so the queries were different  Thank you so much@ Adam